# How to pass variable using get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have three types of posts on my WordPress site (standard, aside, video).
I need to count a variable like `$row` in my standard `content.php` file But I am unable to pass it to `content.php` file.

My `index.php` file code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : 
           $$row = 2;
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
            $row++;
            endwhile;
           endif; ?>
```

my `content.php` file code:

```
<div>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?>- <?php echo $row; ?></p>
</div>
```

but when I `echo $row;` nothing shows

I already use this link [from a similar question on stackoverflow](https://mekshq.com/passing-variables-via-get_template_part-wordpress/) but I can't change my post format file, Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass parameters exactly, but what you can do is use the functions `set_query_var` and `get_query_var` which makes the variables globally accessible.

In the main template, e.g. index.php, you use `set_query_var` to set the variable. Note that the first parameter is the name of the global variable, and this is what you use to retrieve it - not the original parameter name.

```
set_query_var( "my_global_var_name", $param_vaule); 
get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
```

Then in the template part, you can get the value of the now-global variable using `get_query_var`, e.g.

```
$myvar = set_query_var( "my_global_var_name" );
```

(It's worth noting that its best practice to minimise global variables, so you might be netter looking at restructuring your template structure to see if there is another way to do this, using extra template parts for example.)

**References:**

- [Wordpress Developer Resources for `set_query_var`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_query_var/)
- [Wordpress Developer Resources for `get_query_var`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/)

Comment: I just wanted to note that starting with WordPress 5.5, it will now be possible to pass variables. Here's the release announcement: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/

Comment: @ChrisHaas About time :) Thanks for the info!