# How to pass value from WordPress functions.php to any other php file e.g. page template

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to pass a value from functions file to a page template but not sure how to do it
I usually use get template part but since its a function file,

**functions.php**

```
function my_ajax_request() {
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my-ajax-script' ) ) {
    die( 'Nonce value cannot be verified.' );
}

if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
    $color = $_REQUEST['color'];
    if ( $color == 'Black' ) {
        $bgcolor = '#000'; // how to pass value  to other file/page?
        $txtcolor ='#fff'; // how to pass value  to other file/page?
    }
  
}
die();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_request', 'my_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_request', 'my_ajax_request' );
```

**custompage.php**

```
<div style="background:<?php $color; ?>;color:<?php $txtcolor; ?>;">
<p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variable using get\_template\_part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701744/how-to-pass-variable-using-get-template-part/62701948#62701948) The question is not specifically about functions.php but the answer still applies for this case too.

Comment: I read that wordpress 5.5 is going to allow you to do this easily - https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/

Comment: @Aliqua yes, but that’s a month away so it’s not much good to anyone who needs it now!

Comment: Missed that part. Thanks FK :) -- curse of a speed reader